# pandas sort_values returns unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sort a datafarame using the pandas sort_values() function but the returned result is sorted in a strange way as shown in the image attached [image]

Comment: it looks like your Citations column is of type string. Convert it to number then sorting should work

Comment: I checked the `au_df_srtd.dtypes' and it returns `dtype: object` for all columns

Comment: @E.Aly Ok check mine or jezraels answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is column `Citation` is strings repr of numbers, so need convert to numeric by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
au_df['Citation'] = au_df['Citation'].astype(int)
au_df_srtd = au_df.sort_values('Citations')
```

If not working because at least one string value in numbers use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non numbers to `NaN`s:

```
au_df['Citation'] = pd.to_numeric(au_df['Citation'], errors='coerce')
au_df_srtd = au_df.sort_values('Citations')
```

Comment: You're faster 7 sec

Comment: nice one with `to_numeric` tho.

Answer (score 2):

Because they must be strings, so try using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
au_df['Citations'] = au_df['Citations'].astype(int)
au_df_srtd = au_df.sort_values('Citations')
```